# Rails 4 jQuery selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't understand why this is not working; it's seemingly very simple. Class of active is not being [added](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to the [first child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)  of the jQuery selected div with class of carousel-inner.

```
<div id="public-feed-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('div.carousel-inner:first-child').addClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

This is in the show view of a rails app.

Comment: Any errors in the console? jQuery loaded?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined from the console. Although this error seems unrelated.

Comment: Unrelated errors may cause JavaScript to halt execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `div.carousel-inner:first-child`, you're saying "Give me all divs with a class of carousel-inner that are first child's of their parent."

It sounds like you mean, "Give me the first child element of all divs with a class of carousel-inner" which actually looks like this:

```
div.carousel-inner :first-child
```

Comment: This is it; thanks for explaining my mistake. This is what I ended up using `$('div.carousel-inner .item:first-child').addClass("active");` because I believe this is what I was trying to 'say.'

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that another JavaScript transforms the DOM before your function is executed? Try to use `console.debug on $('div.carousel-inner:first-child')` to see, if it exists and where it might be located. Another thing is, that you might want to put your JavaScript in a `document.ready` section, so it is executed after the DOM finished loading.

Comment: A good thought, what you explained has happened to me before but this is a fairly new project so no other js could have snuck its way into manipulating the dom :)